# why does this @Html.Raw() work in firefox and not chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, firefox

Can any one tell me why this piece of code works in Firefox with no issues but in chrome i get a

> System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll.

```
<div id="tabs-1">
    @if (ViewBag.Raw != null)
    {
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Raw)  
    }
</div>
```

I am getting data from the database like this

```
var querys = item.Database.SqlQuery<stuffID>("select Text from stuffFiles where _id=@stuffID", new SqlParameter("@stuffID", id));
```

I am taking the Text i need like this

```
foreach (var items in querys)
{
    paths = items.Text;
}
ViewBag.Raw = paths;
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work in Chrome.

Comment: What's the stack trace?  The browser *really* shouldn't make a difference in server-side code.  I highly suspect something else is wrong.

Comment: When i did a call stack it says  The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.

Comment: A `StackOverflowException` is usually caused by infinite recursion. Simply, every time you do something like create a variable, call a method, etc. you add an item to the stack (a section of memory). It has a finite limit, and when you hit that, boom. However, in this day in age, it's virtually impossible to add enough to the stack with normal code to cause that, which is why it's generally the result of infinite recursion. Long and short, it has *nothing* to do with the browser. If it's working in Firefox, Firefox must be running off cache or something.

Comment: Look for areas of your code where you might be doing `while` loops or method recursion (method that calls itself for some purpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to get it working with this piece of code

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.Raw))
```

From what i understand @Html.Raw renders unencoded HTML so it needs to be decoded first.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is doing what it is not supposed to do.

Did you mean to concat the `text` from all the `items` you get from `querys`

You code below would take into account only the last `item` text and all the previous will be overwritten

```
foreach (var items in querys)
{
    paths = items.Text; //try to replace this with the line below 
    //paths = paths + items.Text + "," ;
}
ViewBag.Raw = paths;
```

I would recommend NOT USING `Html.Raw` except when you know what you are doing. One should use `HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode` instead

Comment: I tried that but didn't work. Using Html.Raw works in firefox and should work in Chrome

Comment: This is the error that comes up.   Symbol loading Skipped. Symbol loading for optimized module System.Web.dll was skipped because Just my code is enabled.

Comment: That's not an error. That's a warning, from Visual Studio, about not being able to load all the symbols for debugging purposes. It only effects your ability to step into the code while debugging. It's not an actual error in your application.